# Rotated Rectangles junction WPF UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, uwp

My purpose is to build the animated checkmark and i use the two rectangles for this. But I can not properly joint these rectangles (this can look nice on one device, but the joint is visible in device with another resolution). My question is how to dock the coordinates of these rectangles in code behind?
XAML Code provided below

```
    <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
    <Rectangle x:Name="RectCheck1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderTransformOrigin="1,1" Fill="{Binding Color,ElementName=check}"  Height="18"  Width="50" Visibility="Visible">
            <Rectangle.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection RotationZ="-45" CenterOfRotationX="0" CenterOfRotationY="0" CenterOfRotationZ="0"/>
            </Rectangle.Projection>
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="RectTrans1" />
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="RectCheck1Draw" Storyboard.TargetName="RectCheck1">
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="RectAnim1Width" EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="50" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="1x" />
            </Storyboard>
            </Rectangle.Resources>
        </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle x:Name="RectCheck2" Fill="{Binding Color,ElementName=check}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="18"   Width="70"  Visibility="Visible">
        <Rectangle.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection RotationZ="45" CenterOfRotationX="0" CenterOfRotationY="0" CenterOfRotationZ="0"/>
        </Rectangle.Projection>

        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="RectTrans2" />
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="RectCheck2Draw" Storyboard.TargetName="RectCheck2">
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="RectAnim2Width" EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="70" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="1x" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Rectangle.Resources>

    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It looks like the top part of your first Rectangle is missing. Did it also have a projection? Can you please also add that code? Are you just trying to move both rectangles position in code?

Comment: Sorry, code is edited now...

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing an issue with layout rounding. Turn off layout rounding in the parent `Grid` and see if the projections/transformations snap properly.

```
<Grid UseLayoutRounding="False">
   <Rectangle ...>
   <Rectangle ...>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, but adds some artefacts :)